# Why system.js returns an empty object instead of angularjs?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs

Why system.js returns an empty object instead of angularjs? How to fix it?

```js
System.config({
  map: {
    angular: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js'
  }
});

System.import('angular').then(function(data){
  console.log('###', data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
System.config({
  map: {
    angular: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js'
  },
  meta: {
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js': {
      'format': 'global'
    }
  }
});

System.import('angular').then(function(data){
  console.log('###', data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because AngularJS is being loaded at the global level, [not as a module.](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/overview.md#loading-es6)

After performing your import, `angular` is available in the global scope.

```js
System.config({
  map: {
    angular: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js'
  }
});

System.import('angular').then(function(){
  console.log(angular);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.js"></script>
```

Comment: @shatal That's right. But instead you gain access to the global `angular` object.